# jQuery: Получить значение произвольного атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть HTML код ссылки с произвольным атрибутом:

```
<a href="#" myattribute="Test">Ссылка номер 1</a>
```

Как с помощью JavaScript или jQuery получить значение этого атрибута?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**С помощью jQuery**

```js
alert($('a[myattribute]').attr('myattribute'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" myattribute="Test">Ссылка номер 1</a>
```

**С помщью JavaScript**

```js
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('A')[0];
alert(myElement.getAttribute('myattribute'));
```

```html
<a href="#" myattribute="Test">Ссылка номер 1</a>
```